# Date filtering PrimeReact Datatable doesn't work

Tags: datatable, primereact

I have a primereact datatable with a date filtering but it doesn't work. It works with the calendar but not when I am typing in the field. The options are then empty:

```
const dateFilterTemplate = (options) =>
    {
        return <Calendar
            value={options.value}  is empty
            onChange={(e) =>
            {
                if (e.value !== null)
                {
                    options.filterApplyCallback(e.value, options.index)
                }
            }}
            dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"
            placeholder="dd-mm-jjjj"
            mask="99/99/9999"
        />
    };
```

I want to be able to filter by clicking on the calendar and by typing in the inputfield. I've created a sandbox: (https://codesandbox.io/s/primereact-datatable-date-filtering-9lxu6j). It is important that the `filterdisplay` stays on `"row"`

UPDATE:
I have it working. I've updated my sandbox.

Comment: I just tried your code sanbox and it works fine?  I was able to filter on a date.

Comment: Also when you only type in the textbox?

Comment: Yes if I type `09/12/2015` and press ENTER the filter fires and the table is filtered to that date